# converting s4 object to data frame or list issue in r

Tags: r, data-mining

i've been trying to implement `apriori algorithm` to my database in r . as i am doing this , i realized that apriori algorithm returns s4 object . actually it's not a problem if i hadn't wanted to write results to database.

i started to write my r code like this ;
at first i load packages releated to my analysis

```
library(DBI)
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(Matrix)
library(grid)
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)

getwd()
setwd("D:/R")
getwd()

jdbcDriver<-JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath = "D:/R/ojdbc6.jar")
jdbcConnection<-dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:oracle:ip:port","user","pass")
ana_sorgu<- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,"SELECT action_id, product_cat FROM table")
urunler<-dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection,"select distinct product_cat from product_cat")

i <- split(ana_sorgu$PRODUCT_CAT,ana_sorgu$ACTION_ID)
txn <- as(i, "transactions")

sorgu2<-as.list(urunler$PRODUCT_CAT)

for(row2 in 1:nrow(urunler)) {
    basket_rules<-apriori(data=txn, parameter=list(supp=0.001,conf = 0.4), appearance = list(default="lhs",rhs=sorgu2[[row2]]))
    deneme<-inspect(basket_rules)#i guess that something has to be changed to write here releated to next for loop but i can't
    for(row in 1:length(basket_rules)) {
        jdbcDriver2<-JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath = "D:/R/ojdbc6.jar", identifier.quote = "\"")
        jdbcConnection2<-dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:oracle:ip:port","user","pass")
        sorgu <- paste0("insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('",deneme$lhs[[row]],"','",deneme$rhs[[row]],"','",deneme$support[[row]],"','",deneme$confidence[[row]],"','",deneme$lift[[row]],"')")
        print(sorgu)
        result<-dbSendUpdate(jdbcConnection2,sorgu)
        dbDisconnect(jdbcConnection2)
}}
```

i have created variable that called sorgu2 to make my analysis dynamiccally product category by product category so i implemented urunler$PRODUCT_CAT in as.list().Therefore i can use it in rhs that in first for loop.

Finally when i execute this cod it returns;

```
Apriori
Parameter specification:
confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
    0.4    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE   0.001      1     10  rules FALSE
Algorithmic control:
filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 854

set item appearances ...[1 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[793 item(s), 854614 transaction(s)] done [0.34s].
sorting and recoding items ... [350 item(s)] done [0.05s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.99s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4 done [0.20s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.12s].
[1] "insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('','','','','')"
[1] "insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('','','','','')"
Apriori

Parameter specification:
 confidence minval smax arem  aval originalSupport support minlen maxlen target   ext
    0.4    0.1    1 none FALSE            TRUE   0.001      1     10  rules FALSE
Algorithmic control:
 filter tree heap memopt load sort verbose
0.1 TRUE TRUE  FALSE TRUE    2    TRUE

Absolute minimum support count: 854

set item appearances ...[1 item(s)] done [0.00s].
set transactions ...[793 item(s), 854614 transaction(s)] done [0.33s].
sorting and recoding items ... [350 item(s)] done [0.05s].
creating transaction tree ... done [0.98s].
checking subsets of size 1 2 3 4 done [0.20s].
writing ... [0 rule(s)] done [0.00s].
creating S4 object  ... done [0.12s].
[1] "insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('','','','','')"
[1] "insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('','','','','')"
Error in asMethod(object) : 
NISASTA PATATES ALGR2 is an unknown item label
```

where did i do wrong? thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a lot of code, little spaces and no reproducibility. Please consider pin-pointing the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `unclass` to see the content of the S4 object produced by `arules` (showing only the first 5 elements of an object that I've called `deneme`, like yours, but obviously with different content):

```
> unclass(deneme[1:5])
<S4 Type Object>
attr(,"quality")
           support confidence      lift
4     0.0001528538        1.0 1362.9583
38    0.0001222830        1.0 1362.9583
27287 0.0001222830        0.8  872.2933
94270 0.0001222830        0.8  872.2933
226   0.0001222830        0.8  817.7750
attr(,"info")
attr(,"info")$data
msweb.trans

attr(,"info")$ntransactions
[1] 32711

attr(,"info")$support
[1] 1e-04

attr(,"info")$confidence
[1] 0.8

attr(,"lhs")
itemMatrix in sparse format with
 5 rows (elements/transactions) and
 284 columns (items)
attr(,"rhs")
itemMatrix in sparse format with
 5 rows (elements/transactions) and
 284 columns (items)
```

You access to each of the attributes using `attr`:

```
> attr(deneme[1:5], "quality")
           support confidence      lift
4     0.0001528538        1.0 1362.9583
38    0.0001222830        1.0 1362.9583
27287 0.0001222830        0.8  872.2933
94270 0.0001222830        0.8  872.2933
226   0.0001222830        0.8  817.7750
```

where `quality` is a dataframe with 3 columns, you may access to each of them using `$`:

```
> attr(deneme[1:5], "quality")$confidence
[1] 1.0 1.0 0.8 0.8 0.8
```

While `lhs` and `rhs` are `itemMatrix` objects, you can get to the actual items using inspect, something like this:

```
as(as(attr(deneme[1:5], "lhs"), "transactions"), "data.frame")$items
```

I'd say with this hints you can modify your code to insert into the database; if you still have doubts please let me know.

Hope it helps.

*EDIT* after your comments: don't use

```
as(as(attr(basket_rules, "lhs"), "transactions"), "data.frame")$items[[row]]
```

but instead

```
as(as(attr(basket_rules[row], "lhs"), "transactions"), "data.frame")$items
```

Your final code will look something like this:

```
for(row2 in 1:nrow(urunler)) {
    basket_rules<-apriori(data=txn, parameter=list(supp=0.001,conf = 0.4), appearance = list(default="lhs",rhs=sorgu2[[row2]]))
    for(row in 1:length(basket_rules)) {
        jdbcDriver2<-JDBC(driverClass = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",classPath = "D:/R/ojdbc6.jar", identifier.quote = "\"")
        jdbcConnection2<-dbConnect(jdbcDriver,"jdbc:oracle:ip:port","user","pass")
        sorgu <- paste0("insert into market_basket_analysis_3 (lhs,rhs,support,confidence,lift) values ('",as(as(attr(basket_rules[row], "lhs"), "transactions"), "data.frame")$items,"','",as(as(attr(basket_rules[row], "rhs"), "transactions"), "data.frame")$items,"','",attr(basket_rules[row],"quality")$support,"','",attr(basket_rules[row],"quality")$confidence,"','",attr(basket_rules[row],"quality")$lift,"')")
        result<-dbSendUpdate(jdbcConnection2,sorgu)
        dbDisconnect(jdbcConnection2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello , really thanks a lot for your help . i think that i will be able to modify my code with your explanation , direction and of course i will let you know if i can't modify it.thanks again

Comment: good nights , i've tried to implement your recommendations on my code , but it gives me an error again that called subscript out of bounds. is it going to be problem that i go on answering my question?